How to extract IP address and port from column in csv file using awk?
My goal is to use awk to parse tcpdump cvs file to extract network tracking and reporting information from columns #22 and #23 (columns and sample data) below:

1,2,3,4,5,6,,....,,22,23,,...
20-09-24,br0,B,UDP,length,127,device1,,...,,50222,,...
20-09-24,eth0,In,TCP,length,60,,...,,167.99.127.131.52842,167.99.127.131.52842,correct,,...
20-09-24,br0,Out,TCP,length,60,,...,,167.99.127.131.52842,167.99.127.131.52842, correct,,...
20-09-24,eth5,Out,TCP,length,60,,...,,167.99.127.131.52842,167.99.127.131.52842, correct,,...
20-09-24,eth5,In,TCP,length,60,,...,,device2,5900,,...

Having some some success learning awk (including above) but having trouble:

Extracting/saving the TCP/IP address only in column #22
Extracting/saving the port address only in column #23

I've searched many sites/solutions and able to correctly identify TCP/IP address and port number in column with the following code:
awk -F, -v OFS=',' --posix '{ if ($22 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,5}/) { $22=-F '\\.' 'print $NF}'

Any suggestions/guidance how to change or replace code to extract/save only TCP/IP address in column #22 and only port number in column #23 similar to (columns and sample data) below:

1,2,3,4,5,6,,...,,22,23,,...
20-09-24,br0,B,UDP,length,127,,...,,device1,50222,,...
20-09-24,eth0,In,TCP,length,60,,...,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct,,...
20-09-24,br0,Out,TCP,length,60,,...,,167.99.127.131,52842, correct,,...
20-09-24,eth5,Out,TCP,length,60,,...,,167.99.127.131,52842 correct,,...
20-09-24,eth5,In,TCP,length,60,,...,,device2,5900,,...


I'm not much of an awk expert either, but the lengthier my one-liners get, the more tempted I am to dump them into separate files with comments. Thankfully, awk lets us load in awk scripts via the -f option.
The data
$ cat data.csv 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
20-09-24,br0,B,UDP,length,127,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,device1,50222,
20-09-24,eth0,In,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct
20-09-24,br0,Out,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct
20-09-24,eth5,Out,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct
20-09-24,eth5,In,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,device2,5900,
$

The awk script
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN {
 # Output field separator of comma
 OFS=",";
 # (input?) field separator as comma
 FS=",";
}
{
 # If we have something that looks like $ip.$port in column 22...
 if ($22 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,5}/) {
     # put the elements of it into `src`
     split($22, src, ".");
     # define our desired separator
     sep=".";
     # redefine $7 based on the pieces we want from `src`
     $22=src[1] sep src[2] sep src[3] sep src[4];
 };
 # If we have something that looks like $ip.$port in column 23...
 if ($23 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,5}/) {
     # put the elements of it into `dst`
     split($23, dst, ".");
     # redefine $8 to be just the port
     $23=dst[5];
 };
 # Print out the entire line
 print $0 ;
}
END{}
$

The output
$ awk --posix -f script.awk data.csv
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
20-09-24,br0,B,UDP,length,127,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,device1,50222,
20-09-24,eth0,In,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct
20-09-24,br0,Out,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct
20-09-24,eth5,Out,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct
20-09-24,eth5,In,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,device2,5900,
$


Hi Preston.  I've spent many days/nights searching and your prompt review/response is magic (thanks)! Noticed "-f" in posts and now know how to use (thanks!).  Along similar line, my project extracting network info from tcpdump requires many awk commands, i.e., "tcpdump -tttt -vi any -c 100 | grep -v "Date:$(date +%F)$" | awk '/^ +/{$1=$1;print q, $0; next} {q=$0}' | awk nnnn (more awk commands)" > tcpdump.csv.  I've piped so many awk commands, awk fails to execute and now need 2 separate pipe command groups ... should I consider placing the 2 groups of pipe commands in one awk script file?

That depends on whether or not the sequential awk commands depend on work done in prior invocations. If each awk command is, say, manipulating a different target column, then yes, you could merge all of the manipulations into a single awk script pretty easily. If however, your awk commands are operating on the same column, one after another, then it may be better to start off with separate scripts for each invocation before trying to compress it all into one script.

Got it, guidance appreciated, and I'll evaluate sequences of awk command invocations for consideration into script, i.e., some delete rows, some delete columns, some extract patterns in columns, etc.

Got it, guidance appreciated, and I'll evaluate sequences of awk command invocations for consideration/consolidation into script, i.e., some delete rows, some delete columns, some extract patterns in columns, etc. I've applied the awk script to my project and run into a snag ... my project rows actually have 30+ columns and target columns are 22 and 23: 2024-09-20, 02:55:53.434557, eth5, Out, IP, tos, 0x0, ttl, 43, id, 21354, offset, 0, flags, [DF], proto, TCP, 6, length, 52, , 167.99.127.131.52842, 167.99.127.131.52842,,,,... The target rows are 22 and 23.

if ($22 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,5}/) {
# put the elements of it into twentytwo
split($22, twentytwo, ".");
# define our desired separator
sep=".";
# redefine $22 based on the pieces we want from twentytwo
$22=twentytwo[1] sep twentytwo[2] sep twentytwo[3] sep twentytwo[4];

Sorry, forget to add in previous comment I tried to edit the code you provide earlier.

You can eliminate the ifs by using awk's condition/action syntax, and instead of split and then rebuild, you can do $7 ~ ... { sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,"",$7) }; similarly $8 ~ ... { sub(/^.*\./,"",$8) }

Hi Dave.  Response appreciated. One tweak needed ... my data row actually has 30+ columns and modifications needed on column 22 and column 23.  I tried the following but column 22 remains the same (.port) not removed: awk -F, -v OFS=',
' '($22 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,5}/) { sub(/
.[0-9]+$/,"",$22) } 1' tcpdump.txt, i.e., 2024-09-20, 02:55:53.434557, eth5, Out, IP, tos, 0x0, ttl, 43, id, 21354, offset, 0, flags, [DF], proto, TCP, 6, length, 52, , 167.99.127.131.52842, 167.99.127.131.52842,,,,....

I've adjusted the answer to work on columns 22 and 23. If you're able to update your question with the current state of your input and script(s), we might be able to spot a mistake/bug more easily than in the comments here.

Hi Preston. I tried the updated script.awk code and no errors but columns 22 and 23 remain unchanged.  As suggested, I've updated the original question to expand actual dataset.  Patience appreciated as I learn not taking shortcuts with data sample.

Using guidance provided by Preston (thanks!), I slightly tweaked his code as follows:
# If we have something that looks like $ip.$port in column 22, then extract $ip/save in column 22 and extract $port/save in column 23
if ($22 ~ /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,5}/) {
     # put the elements of it into `src`
     {split($22,src,".")};
     # define our desired separator
     sep=".";
     # redefine $22 based on the pieces we want from `src`
#     print src[1] sep src[2] sep src[3] sep src[4];
     $22=src[1] sep src[2] sep src[3] sep src[4];
     $23=src[5];
}```

